# How to allocate space to JAVA using command line

Tags: java

I have come across heap errors while loading a large dataset into Jena. `Is there some way by which I may allocate the JVM(Java) a large heap space.

I know I can achieve this by making changes into eclipse.ini. But is there some way by which I may increase the Java heap size using command line in linux (I using a 64GB RAM server: running 12.04 Ubuntu LTS server)?

The error which I am getting due to less heap space is: exception in thread main gc overhead limit exceeded.

Also how can I find the maximum amount of heap space which I can set for my systems

I tried export JAVA_OPTS= -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m but ended up getting the error:
bash: export: `-Xms4096m': not a valid identifier
bash: export:`-Xmx4096m': not a valid identifier

Comment: research `Xmx` and `Xms` options

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I tried but setting them through JVM_OPTIONS does not work for me. Also how can I find the maximum amount of heap space which I can set for my systems. Thanks a lot for replying...i read the post before posting the question..but since I am a novice at linux..i did not get much

Comment: this kind of information is easy to find with any search engine.

Comment: @Leo Ya I tried ...but being a novice i am not able to comprehend much

Comment: @AliceEverett You could try running the command `free` on your bash prompt.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks for helping again. I tried export JAVA_OPTS= -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m but ended up getting the error
bash: export: `-Xms4096m': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `-Xmx4096m': not a valid identifier

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try (note quotes are not optional with two words)

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms4096m -Xmx4096m"
```

Or, even

```
export MIN="4096m" # <-- Those quotes are (one word).
export MAX="4096m"
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms$MIN -Xmx$MAX" # <-- single quotes would break variable expansion
```

Comment: I have 64 GB RAM..is it fine If I allocate 16GB RAM for Java heap space

Comment: @AliceEverett Test it, but I might go even higher... (depending on what I was doing)...

Comment: also what does the "m" in export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms4096m -Xmx4096"..signify..i m just a little curious..thanks a lot for the help thus far

Comment: @AliceEverett Megabytes...

Comment: @AliceEverett Also, try `java -X -help`.

Comment: should there be an m after -Xmx4096 in export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms4096m -Xmx4096"

Answer (score 5):

```
java -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m [YourAppHere]
```

This command will allocate 4GB (or 4096 MB) of heap memory at the start (the -Xms4096m option), and will have a maximum heap memory size of 4GB (the -Xmx4096m option).

Obviously you can change the number to whatever sizes you want to.  There is overhead if the computer has to increase the size of memory (Every time it increases the memory size, it doubles the allocation) so if you have that much ram, you might as well just allocate it at the beginning of the app.

Comment: what does [YourAppHere] signify. Also thanks for answering :)

Comment: the java file that you are running

Comment: actually I am running java bytecodes(i.e. executable equivalent of C++)..can I specify the executable name here

Comment: Also is there a way by which I may set java heap size permanently for some time

Comment: java is always run as bytecode, whether it's just compiled, or compressed into a jar.  Java runs on a virtual machine and only understands bytecode specifically made for it.  Those commands will set the heap size to whatever you want them to be and it is persistant as long as the app is running.  if you need a shortcut write a sh script that calls that command instead of typing it everytime

Comment: @AliceEverett You can write a script file to start your program, then you run the script...

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping..but i tried with apache-jena-2.10.0 (Inside bin binaries are kept) and it gives me the Error: Could not find or load main class ..tdbloader

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I tried but with binaries kept in bin of apache-jena..its gives me the error mentioned above. Thanks a lot for replying :)

Comment: The method which I used for loading files is: bin/tdbloader --loc=/home/sysadmin/mydatasetdata -v /full/path/to/rdf/or/ttl/files/